# ListBox specific row/item coloring Diffrent Color C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, background-color

I need to Mark the first item in the ListBox in a different way like in a different color. if i have `listbox` is there a way to color the first item in it Red preferred programmatically.

ListBox:

```
 List<CartItem> CartListItem = CartItem.getListOfCartItems(myCart, Items);
 dgProduct.ItemsSource = Items;
```

Xaml

```
 <ListBox Name="dgProduct" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,41,10,0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
             ">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                 </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `AlternationCount` on the `ListBox` and then use a `StyleTrigger` for `index 0`.

```
 <ListBox Name="dgProduct" 
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
          Margin="0,41,10,0" 
          Grid.RowSpan="3"
          AlternationCount="1000">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
                .
                .
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: @NitzanFarhi, also attributes are case sensitive. Make sure its "Background" and not "BackGround"